# angular2 let-entity directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I've create a component which takes in a template:

```
export class TemplateParamComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() items: Array<any>;
    @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;
 }
```

With html:

```
<template #defaultTemplate let-item="item">
    <strong>{{item.name}}</strong>
</template>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template || defaultTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="{item: item}"></template>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm confused on what the directive let-item does,  does that create a variable called item?  is let a special directive that lets you declare variable to use in scope for html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best suggestion for you to understand how angular handle `<template>` element is reading documentation: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Long story short: consider `<template>` as function (method) and `let-something` as input variable. So

```
<template #defaultTemplate let-item="item">
     <strong>{{item.name}}</strong>
</template>
```

Can be read as

```
function defaultTemplate(item: any){
    return "<strong>" + item.name + "</strong>";
}
```