# Is it possible to assign a value to a variable with let in an angular component template?

Tags: angular, angular-template

Consider this snippet:

```
<div class="col-4" style="text-align: center;">
    <skin-stat-circle>{{statByType('Users')?.count}}</skin-stat-circle><br>
    <span>{{statByType('Users')?.label}}</span>
</div>
```

Is it possible to assign `statByType('Users')` to a local template variable a bit like as in `*ngFor` using `let...` ?

**Edit**

Worked it out with the help of @incaner. This is powerful - like it a lot.

```
<ng-template #statTemplate let-stat="stat">
   <div class="col-4" *ngIf="stat">
      <skin-stat-circle >{{stat.count}}</skin-stat-circle>
      <br>
      <span>{{stat.label}}</span>
   </div>
</ng-template>
<skin-stat-group>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="statTemplate;context:{stat: statByType('Users')}"></ng-container>
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="statTemplate;context:{stat: statByType('Projects')}"></ng-container>
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="statTemplate;context:{stat: statByType('Layers')}"></ng-container>
      </div>
   </div>
</skin-stat-group>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try using the let-* directive:

```
<ng-template let-variable="statByType('Users')?.count"> 
  {{variable}}
</ng-template>
```

and then simply use the template.

If you need more help read the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax)

Comment: Very interesting, I have never heard of this directive. I searched the Docs and couldn't find anything on it. Do you know where this directive is located in the Angular Docs or source? I am curious to learn more about it. I did see this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909568/angular2-let-entity-directive) which again mentions it - but provides no further info

Comment: @Narm added a link to the angular docs. There isnt much you can read. I think the angular team added the let directive, so that we can get the "odd" and "index" from a current ngFor loop. And since you can use the ngFor directive inside a ng-template its obligatory to be able to define variables inside a template. I rarely use this, it does not seem to be best practice.

Comment: Microsyntax - very cool. I am not sure I will ever need to use it, but it is good to know the option exists in case I ever do. I appreciate the info, thanks for updating your answer with a link to the Docs!

Comment: I think its useful - the argument would be why not a new component? But it's for such a piddly display only amount of html and the context is so local, I wouldn't want to end up with loads of small components like these.

Answer (score 2):

Worked it out with the help of @incaner. This is powerful - like it a lot.

```
<ng-template #statTemplate let-stat="stat">
   <div class="col-4" *ngIf="stat">
      <skin-stat-circle >{{stat.count}}</skin-stat-circle>
      <br>
      <span>{{stat.label}}</span>
   </div>
</ng-template>
<skin-stat-group [title]="">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="statTemplate;context:{stat: statByType('Users')}"></ng-container>
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="statTemplate;context:{stat: statByType('Projects')}"></ng-container>
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="statTemplate;context:{stat: statByType('Layers')}"></ng-container>
      </div>
   </div>
</skin-stat-group>
```

Comment: I think it would be useful for future lads if you put this as an edit in your question